# Get access to images paths with external text editor (SublimeText for Example)

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files, data-blocks, text-editor

I want to quickly manipulate images paths in blender files with [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/) as lists.

Maybe I can open blend. files like Zip Archives and edit data-blocks as simple text files?

Maybe I can quickly export files paths of desired datablocks, edit them, and then import back to blend. file?

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure I follow but blend files are written in binary format, you won't be able to read them with a regular text editor. Apart from the first few characters which are the version number and such which are in plain text format.